# SQL get only different entries between 2 tables based on 2 key parameters

Tags: mysql

Basically I have a 2 tables with the same structure( Accounts and New_accounts). New_accounts has more entries than Accounts so I need to grab only the ones that dont exist in Accounts.

Unfortunately I can just sort them by different id's. The only thing that is the same between the two tables to rely on is a combo pair of `dist_abbv` and `vip_id`. On no entry will another have the same pair on it. So entry `A` will have a combo of `dist_abbv` and `vip_id` that is unique to only that entry. That is the way to tell if it exists in both tables.

Table Fields:

```
id | name | address | city | state | zip | phone | email | vip_id | dist_abbv
```

I tried this, but I know (via # of rows) that this isnt returning the accurate entries

```
SELECT new_accounts.*
    FROM new_accounts
    LEFT JOIN accounts 
    ON (accounts.vip_id = new_accounts.vip_id AND accounts.name = new_accounts.name)
    WHERE (accounts.vip_id = new_accounts.vip_id AND accounts.name = new_accounts.name) IS NULL
```

Comment: Could you please post some data as it becomes difficult to visualize about scenario ?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `WHERE` clause to

```
WHERE accounts.vip_id is NULL AND accounts.name is NULL
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Could even just say

```
WHERE accounts.id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT new_accounts.*
FROM new_accounts
LEFT JOIN accounts 
ON (accounts.vip_id = new_accounts.vip_id AND accounts.name = new_accounts.name)
HAVING accounts.id = NULL
```

Since joining will do the equate condition, just filter the result using the HAVING will fetch the desired result

Answer (score 0):

This is called a "left anti semi join", and since it uses a negative join predicate, the query performance varies greatly depending on indexes, your query approach, and the database engine you are using.

Here are the methods I know of, each of which will potentially perform differently:

**NOT EXISTS**

```
SELECT *
FROM new_accounts
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM accounts
    WHERE accounts.vip_id = new_accounts.vip_id AND accounts.name = new_accounts.name
)
```

**IS NULL**

```
SELECT new_accounts.*
FROM new_accounts
LEFT JOIN accounts 
    ON accounts.vip_id = new_accounts.vip_id
    AND accounts.name = new_accounts.name
WHERE accounts.vip_id IS NULL
```

**EXCEPT**

*Note: This does not work in MySQL.  Also, this method only works if `new_accounts` and `accounts` have exactly the same schema.  Normally you would do this operation selecting a single column of like type*

```
SELECT *
FROM new_accounts
EXCEPT
SELECT *
FROM accounts
```

Comment: MySQL doesn't support `EXCEPT` AFAIK

Comment: Thanks, you're dead right. I didn't see the MySQL tag on the original post. I've updated the answer to reflect that caveat.